# Await question in Javascript async functions

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

```
async abc(){
await some().then(() => {
   //do inside then
});

//other code 
}
```

Does the "await" wait only on the some() or does it await the some() and its then() before going to //other code? Basically the question is does the await wait also on the then part to be done before moving to next statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`some().then()` returns a new promise and the `await` waits on that new promise so it will wait for the `.then()` handler and any promise that it might return before going on past the `await`.  In other words, it waits for that entire promise chain.

---

In general, this is not great style to mix `await` and `.then()` in the same statement as you would typically want to stick with `await` instead of `.then()` as in:

```
async abc(){
    let result = await some();
    // do something with result

    //other code 
}
```

This gives you the simpler looking and more sequential code design that `await` enables.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use arrow function to achieve this.

```
  const some = () => 'something';

  const abs = async () => {

     const result_from_some = await some();

     // do something with result_from_some
   }
```

But please, if the value in '**result_from_some**' may change, then is better to use **let** instead of **const**

Hope this helps someone.